# Genfromtxt skips information with #

Tags: python, csv, comments, genfromtxt, import-csv

I have a problem with reading in a CSV file with # signs. The CSV looks like this.

```
 aaa;;xxx;aaa;aaa;aaa;xxx;xxx;xxx;xxx;xxx;xxx;aaa
```

with `aaa` as a string and xxx as float. But in this file there is a line like this:

```
aaa;;aaa;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A
```

Python keeps saying that this line would have 4 columns instead of 13. He interprets the # as a comment and skips the rest of it. I tried:

```
kwargs = dict(delimiter=';',
          dtype=np.str,
          skip_header=11,
          usecols= range(1,14),
          missing_values = "#N/A",
          filling_values = "0")
data = np.genfromtxt(TestFile, **kwargs)
```

but still couldn't get it to work.

How could I manage that?

Comment: How do you read and evaluate the file? Show us the code.

Comment: What do you mean by read and evaluate the file. I've look through it and it contains all information which is necessary

Comment: Show us the code you use to read the file and extract each value from the CSV.

Comment: 'kwargs = dict(delimiter=';',
              dtype=np.str,
              skip_header=11,
              usecols= range(1,14),
              missing_values = "#N/A",
              filling_values = "0")
data = np.genfromtxt(RigFile, **kwargs)'

Comment: Please edit your question and fill that in. Otherwise it is unreadable.

Comment: @mrCarnivore can you help me with that?

Comment: You specified missing values as #N/A so no wonder it thinks that there are only 4 instead of 13 values. The other are missing according to your own definition.

Comment: I may have missunderstood the genfromtxt, but wouldn't he fill in 0 if he find a #N/A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the dictionary to,

```
kwargs = dict(delimiter=';',
              dtype=np.str,
              skip_header=11,
              usecols= range(1,14),
              missing_values = "#N/A",
              filling_values = "0",
              comments=None)
```

Now, this should work. However, I'm not sure why you're using columns 1-13 when there are only columns from 0-12.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works for me. I am reading columns 1-13 because the real csv has more columns...